# WPF StaticResource: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: wpf

I have a resource dictionary containing the following:

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RowAlt"
                     Color="Gray" />
<Style x:Key="MainTreeRowStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type dxg:RowControl}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="ShowHorizontalLine"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ShowVerticalLines"
                Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding AlternateRow}"
                               Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Black" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource RowAlt}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

The above is throwing an exception

> " An item with the same key has already been added."

If i replace

```
 <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="{StaticResource RowAlt}" />
```

with

```
 <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="{DynamicResource RowAlt}" />
```

No exception is thrown. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource lies in how the resources are retrieved by the referencing elements. StaticResource are retrieved only once by the referencing element and used for entire life of the resource. On the other hand, DynamicResource are acquired every time the referenced object is used.

Comment: okay, but this does not explain why the "" An item with the same key has already been added." exception is thrown.